# С# Удалить блок текста заключенный в фигурные скобки с условием

Tags: c#, json

Есть лог файл в json формате.
Мне необходимо удалить лишние строки заключенные в фигурные скобки в которых есть "processName": "GM_Scheduler"

```
{ "time": "2018-05-11T00:00:19.075+07:00", "processName": "GM_Scheduler", "processID": "3648", "threadID": "16", "level": "INFO", "message": "Начало выполнения задачи", "computer": "R54-633564-N", "logger": "GM_Scheduler.Global.Log.JobExecutorLog.Executing", "dataareaid": "rp", "storeid": "633564", "terminalid": "633564.00", "operatorname": "", "data": {"JobID":"0001009470"} }
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы JSON десериализовали в структуру классов уже?

Comment: Да, десериализацию я провел

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема? `MyItems.Remove(item => item.PropcessName == "GM_Scheduler")`

Comment: `File.ReadLines.Where(x=>!x.Contains("\"processName\": \"GM_Scheduler\"")).ToArray();`